# How can I get livereload working for webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to use webpackdevserver and reactjs and could not find how to get my livereload working? This is my config settings:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/app.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        publicPath: "/dist/",
        filename: "foss.js",
        sourceMapFilename: "foss.map"
    },
    devtool: '#source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            loader: 'babel',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    },
    devServer: { inline: true }

}
```

Is this a webpack option or do I need to setup elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a live reload feature of [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) package.
You have already specified "inline" option in the devServer section, so you don't need to add something else (except of "noInfo" key to hide wall of text in the output).

```
npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev
webpack-dev-server
```